# Android animation only starts after AsyncTask completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

I am trying to create a native login screen, where the username and password boxes slide off the screen while the request is being processed (and slide back up if the login is unsuccessful).

In order to achieve that, I have defined my animation (`DropDownAnimation`) and I assign it to my `LinearLayout` (footer). When the user clicks the Login button, I start the animation, and then call a function (`tryLogin()`) which starts an `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` handles all the work of creating and sending the login request, and getting the `JSONObject` response.

However, my problem is that the `slideDown` animation doesn't start until after the `AsyncTask` has completed. This doesn't look so bad on a successful login, but on a failed login it means that the `LinearLayout` never slides down - it jumps to the bottom of the screen, to begin the `slideUp` animation back to its original position.

This seems like a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703833/progressdialog-does-not-display-until-after-asynctask-completes), but I'm not doing using `bindService()` and all my non-UI code seems (to me) to be contained in the `AsyncTask` already. LogCat tells me:

`06-24 04:37:35.141: I/Choreographer(5347): Skipped 137 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I assume those are the frames where the footer would be sliding down - but I can't figure out where it is that I'm executing things on the main thread. Here's my code for LoginPage and LoginTask.

**LoginPage.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    footer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);

    // We must wait for the layout to be finalised before trying to find heights.
    ViewTreeObserver vto = footer.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            initAnimations();
        }
    });

    loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                            // Neither of these two things happen until after LoginTask is done.
            footer.startAnimation(slideDown);
            loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

            tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
        }
    });
}

protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword) {
    Exception e;
    String loginUrl = getString(R.string.login_url);
    String clientId = getString(R.string.client_id);
    String clientSecret = getString(R.string.client_secret);
    LoginTask loginTask = (LoginTask) new LoginTask().execute(mUsername, mPassword, loginUrl, clientId, clientSecret);
    if ((e = loginTask.getException()) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        JSONObject response;
        try {
            response = loginTask.get();
            Log.d("login", response.toString());
            if (!response.has("access_token")) {
                loading.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
                footer.startAnimation(slideUp);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, FullscreenWebView.class);
                i.putExtra("accessToken", response.get("access_token").toString());
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginTask.java**

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;
        JSONObject response = null;
        String parameters = "grant_type=password&username="+params[0]+"&password="+params[1]+"&client_id="+params[3]+"&client_secret="+params[4];

        try {
            url = new URL(params[2]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();

            // username or password is probably wrong
            Log.d("login", ""+connection.getResponseCode());
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                return new JSONObject();
            }
            String line = "";
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            Log.d("login", sb.toString());
            response = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

            isr.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

I've also tried making `LoginTask` be a member class of `LoginPage`, and starting the animation in the `onPreExecute()` method, but that didn't change anything.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `AsyncTask.get()`, you are blocking the UI thread. As the animation runs on the UI thread, it appears as if it is not running (while in fact it is blocked by your long running `tryLogin` method).

Instead, you should move the code that relies on the result from the `LoginTask` to its `onPostExecute` method:

```
protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword) {
    String loginUrl = getString(R.string.login_url);
    String clientId = getString(R.string.client_id);
    String clientSecret = getString(R.string.client_secret);
    new LoginTask().execute(mUsername, mPassword, 
        loginUrl, clientId, clientSecret);
}
```

**LoginTask.java**

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Unchanged
    }

    public void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        if (exception != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("login", response.toString());
            if (!response.has("access_token")) {
                loading.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
                footer.startAnimation(slideUp);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, FullscreenWebView.class);
                i.putExtra("accessToken", response.get("access_token").toString());
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, this worked great. There are a couple of errors in your sample code (mostly context things - I don't have access to `loading` or `footer` in the context of `LoginTask`, nor does `Toast.makeText` take `LoginTask` as an argument). 

Because of this I needed to make `LoginTask` a member class of `LoginPage` and reference everything through `LoginPage`. Is there a way to avoid this? Or do I just have to accept having all that functionality in one file?

Comment: @MattRowland - there's no reason you can't pass a `Context` and `TextView`s into your `LoginTask`'s constructor (which currently is just the default, no parameter constructor).

Comment: Ah great! I didn't really know Context could be used like that. This has really improved my code for this, I think. Thanks again, Ian!